# In C Programming Language , where(i.e. in which register of the microprocessor) are the register storage class variables stored?

Tags: c, cpu-registers, microprocessors, storage-class-specifier

Any fixed registers for register storage class

Comment: Varies (and a compiler is allowed to ignore `register`). Your best bet is to study the assembly that the compiler produces.

Comment: In the general-purpose ones. Or in none.

Comment: Seems too broad to me. "Even being microprocessor" does that mean you want *any* examples, from any compiler, regardless of whether they're generally representative, or what?

Answer (score 4):

`register` is an *suggestion* to the compiler that it *might* want to place the specified variable in a register.

It is not a command that it *must* put it in a register.

The compiler can choose which register to put the variable in, or ignore the suggestion completely.

Answer (score 3):

In the previous century, `register` was a *hint* for the compiler to try to put that variable in a [processor register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register).

Today, on most compilers, that hint is nearly ignored. But you still are not allowed to take the address (using `&` unary operator) of a variable declared `register`. So today `register` means "I won't take the address of that variable" to the compiler (hence, `register` storage class is almost never used in recently written code). Some people think that `register` could be deprecated in future standards (of C & C++) or that keyword would be reused for other purposes.

[Optimizing compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) have sophisticated [register allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) and [instruction scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_scheduling) (see also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065)). Details depend upon the level of optimization, the target processor's [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture), the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), etc... So a given variable may be ignored entirely (if the compiler don't need it), or can sit in a register, or can sit in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), etc... (and that status could vary in different points of your compiled function).

With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), you could compile your `foo.c` file with `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S foo.c` and look into the generated `foo.s` assembler file (and you could [vary](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) the optimization level, e.g. with `-O2` etc...).

Regarding performance, today the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) matters a lot, much more than just registers.